# Как сделать правильный формат вывода?

Tags: java, массивы

Задание: Реализовать функцию вывода линейного массива чисел с плавающей запятой с ограничением до 2х знаков после запятой. Обработать ситуацию с пустым массивом. **Формат вывода: (3.14, 2.72, 6.72, -2.34, 1.20, 1235.00)**.

Я уже обрезал число до 2-х знаков после запятой, но никак не могу понять, как сделать, чтобы скобки были только в начале и в конце (сейчас же получается вот так: **(2.43, )(2.45, )(4.21, )(6.32, )(35.32, )(24.21, )**), и, чтобы после последнего числа не было запятой

P.S код

```
double[] arr = {2.4264, 2.4543, 4.2125, 6.32315, 35.32125, 24.21234};
        if (arr.length != 0) {
            double b = 0;
            DecimalFormat formattedDouble;
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                b = arr[i];
                formattedDouble = new DecimalFormat("#0.00");
                for (Double n : Arrays.asList(b)) {
                    Double d = n.doubleValue();
                    String str = "(" + formattedDouble.format(b) + ", " + ")"; //я понимаю, что это скорее всего не правильно, но я хотел от этой части как-то отталкиваться и форматировать
                }
            }
        } else System.out.println("( )");
```

Comment: Вы бы свой код привели, чтобы можно было показать, где вы ошиблись или как доделать правильно.

Comment: А, ок, сейчас добавлю

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
double[] arr = { 3.14, 2.72, 6.72, -2.34, 1.2, 1235 };

System.out.print("(");
for ( int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    System.out.printf("%.2f", arr[i]);
    if ( i != arr.length - 1 ) {
        System.out.print(", ");
    }
}
System.out.print(")");
```

Либо как-то так:

```
System.out.println(
    Arrays.toString(Arrays.stream(arr).mapToObj(e -> String.format("%.2f", e)).toArray())
        .replace('[', '(')
        .replace(']', ')')
);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Comment: Да, вижу, спасибо, но лямбду пока не изучал, так что воспользуюсь первым вариантом